# __ipow__ raising TypeError when left-hand-side object returns NotImplemented

Tags: python-3.x, operators, in-place

If I have two objects `A` and `B`, I can return `NotImplemented` for `A`'s `__iadd__` method and have `B` modify `A` using it's `__radd__` method.

```py
>>> class A():
...     def __init__(self, val):
...         self.val = val
...     def __iadd__(self, other):
...         return NotImplemented
...     def __ipow__(self, other):
...         return NotImplemented 
... 
>>> class B():
...     def __init__(self, val):
...         self.val = val
...     def __radd__(self, other):
...         return A(other.val + self.val)
...     def __rpow__(self, other):
...         return A(other.val ** self.val) 
... 
>>> a = A(2)
>>> b = B(2)
>>> a += b
>>> a.val
4
```

This seems to work for all inplace operators with the exception of `__ipow__` where a `TypeError` is raised.

```py
>>> a **= b
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'A' and 'B'
```

Why is the behavior different here? Is this failing because [`pow()` requires numeric data](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#pow)? What is the best workaround for this?

Comment: What Python version, *exactly*, are you using?

Comment: Using python 3.6.8

Comment: Also reproducible in CPython 3.7. I took the liberty of reporting this: https://bugs.python.org/issue38302

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Python 3.10+

This bug is fixed in [Python 3.10](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=data%20model#object.__ipow__)

> Due to a bug in the dispatching mechanism for `**=`,
> a class that defines `__ipow__()` but returns NotImplemented
> would fail to fall back to `x.__pow__(y)` and `y.__rpow__(x)`.
> This bug is fixed in Python 3.10.

The snippet now works as expected:

```py
>>> a = A(2)
>>> b = B(2)
>>> a **= b
>>> a.val
4
```

---

This looks like a bug due to an inconsistency between the code for binary and ternary operations (with `**=` being handled by the ternary operation logic due to sharing code with 3-argument `pow`). Binary in-place operations go through [`binary_iop1`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.8/Objects/abstract.c#L1023), which has code to fall back to the non-in-place routine if the in-place handler returns `NotImplemented`:

```
static PyObject *
binary_iop1(PyObject *v, PyObject *w, const int iop_slot, const int op_slot)
{
    PyNumberMethods *mv = v->ob_type->tp_as_number;
    if (mv != NULL) {
        binaryfunc slot = NB_BINOP(mv, iop_slot);
        if (slot) {
            PyObject *x = (slot)(v, w);
            if (x != Py_NotImplemented) {
                return x;
            }
            Py_DECREF(x);
        }
    }
    return binary_op1(v, w, op_slot);
}
```

but because of code differences necessary for 3-argument `pow`, `**=` can't go through that code path, so it has [its own ad-hoc handling](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.8/Objects/abstract.c#L1144):

```
PyObject *
PyNumber_InPlacePower(PyObject *v, PyObject *w, PyObject *z)
{
    if (v->ob_type->tp_as_number &&
        v->ob_type->tp_as_number->nb_inplace_power != NULL) {
        return ternary_op(v, w, z, NB_SLOT(nb_inplace_power), "**=");
    }
    else {
        return ternary_op(v, w, z, NB_SLOT(nb_power), "**=");
    }
}
```

This ad-hoc handling commits to either the in-place or non-in-place side, with no fallback if the in-place handler can't handle it.

Comment: Also reproducible in CPython 3.7

Comment: I took the liberty of reporting this: 
https://bugs.python.org/issue38302